# PMD coulnd't find ruleset

Tags: java, maven-plugin, pom.xml, pmd

I'm on creating a maven based java project, which contains the PMD maven plugin. I use my own rule set XML and it works like a charm, except two rule sets: the **emptycode** and the **unnecessary**: when I run the build, maven says: "*can't find resource*". The role definitions look like:

```
<role ref="rulesets/emptycode" />
```

and

```
<role ref="rulesets/unnecessary" />
```

In every other cases, this kind of definition works. What I found out is that: there is a rule set with the name "**unnecessary**" under *ecmasrcipt* category, so maybe this definition needs some suggestion to use java version. I tried multiple thinks, like set *language* attribute to the *ruleset* xml node ("JAVA", based on PMD JavaDoc), and some pre-postfix in *ref*, but it doesn't work and I found no working solution over the web. Does someone has an idea, what I forgot to set, or what I fail? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10):

PMD seems to be a fiddly beastie to use from Maven. I've just figured this out with version 3.0 of the plugin - there are two solutions:

- **The quick-and-dirty solution**: put rulesets in your project:

  - download the PMD jar (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/latest/download)
  - extract `lib/pmd-x.x.x.jar`
  - extract from that PMD jar file the `rulesets/<type>/<ruleset>.xml` files you want to use
  - place them in a folder under your project - something like `${basedir}/pmd/...`
  - reference them as follows:

    ```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <rulesets>
                <ruleset>${basedir}/pmd/<ruleset>.xml</ruleset>
            </rulesets>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ```

    The advantage is this is easy, the disadvantage is if you update the PMD version in future you'll need to remember to update these files.
- **The nice solution**: reference rulesets in `pmd-x.x.x.jar`.

  - create a custom ruleset such as: `${basedir}/pmd/custom.xml` (see http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.2/howtomakearuleset.html)
  - reference the PMD rulesets in the following way: `<rule ref="rulesets/java/imports.xml"/>`
  - **NB:** the path is the path inside `pmd-x.x.x.jar` (see quick-and-dirty above) *with no leading slash*
  - reference your custom ruleset as follows:

    ```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <rulesets>
                <ruleset>${basedir}/pmd/custom.xml</ruleset>
            </rulesets>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ```

    The advantage is this will always reference the current PMD rulesets from the PMD jar, the disadvantage is it's a bit fiddly to get right.

To experiment with this until it was working (`maven-pmd-plugin` version 3.0) I kept running mvn pmd:pmd (`<linkXref>false</linkXref>` in `pom.xml`) and tweaked the paths until I stopped getting errors.

Comment: Did they maybe change how things are deployed? I don't see a pmd-x-x-x.jar as of 5.7.0.